# German book where a hiring manager hires his former bully

Tags: identification-request, german-language

I am trying to find a German book from which I read an excerpt when I was in high school studying German (between 1997 and 1999). In that book a manager at a company is reviewing applications for an opening at his companies when he finds one sent by his former bully. At least on paper, his former bully seems perfect for the job so the manager is confronted with the decision of hiring him.

The story takes place in the 20th century, probably after the Second World War. I don't have any more information about that book, I am just hoping it will remind something to a user here.

Comment: Welcome to Literature Stack Exchange! We don't know when you were in high school. Could you provide a year or even a decade? Are you sure that the book was originally written in German (which is the point of the [[tag:german-literature]] tag), or could it have been a translation? I know you said you don't have more information about the book, but maybe look at the tag wiki for [[identification-request](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info)] for ideas of what kind of extra information would be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the edit and for adding the [identification-request] tag, @bobble. I will edit my question shortly to add a time from when I was in high school, and check the other identification requests. And yes, I am sure the book was originally written in German.

Comment: Reminds me of a real-life story where a successful Frank Sinatra is approached by a former bully for a job and he gives him a demeaning position as a "gofer."